# Three-step construction: Euclid's fourth proportional

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

**PROBLEM** Straight from Euclid's proposition on the fourth proportional, here is a surprisingly intriguing historical challenge posed on Euclidea, a mobile app for Euclidean constructions. I have a geometric construction that achieves the goal but not within the constraints. Could anyone advise on a construction that would fit within these constraints?

> **Given** $\angle{O}$. Points $A$ and $B$ are on one ray of $\angle{O}$ in the order $O-A-B$, and $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ is completely preconstructed. Point $C$ is on the other ray of $\angle{O}$.
>
> **Goal** Construct point $D$ on the same ray of $\angle{O}$ as $C$, such that $$\frac{OA}{OB} = \frac{OC}{OD}.$$
>
> **Constraints** Only an unmarked straightedge and a *non-rusty collapsible* compass (*i.e.*, a compass that, while on paper, can have any radius but which cannot maintain said radius when not on paper) can be used. Use only from the construction steps below a number of steps that together require just *three* elementary steps in total.
>
> 1. Construct a point: 0 steps (S).
> 2. Mark the intersection of two curves with a point: 0S.
> 3. Construct a new line (*or line segment or ray): 1S.
> 4. Extend a *given* line segment (*or ray): 1S.
> 5. Construct a circle (*non-rusty collapsible* compass): 1S.
> 6. Construct the perpendicular bisector of a line segment: 3S.
> 7. Construct a new line perpendicular to an old line: 3S.
>
> **Hints from Euclidea** A known solution employs three constructions in the order: Circle, circle, line.

**PREVIOUS WORK** Following Euclid himself, I constructed below a line $\overleftrightarrow{BF} \parallel \overline{OA}$; $\overleftrightarrow{BF}$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OC}$ at the required point $D$. But my construction barely misses both the 3S-constraint and the hint. The following figure accompanies my four-step construction, where the given and goal are shown as an inset:

[image: 4S construction to this problem]

1. Construct $\bigcirc{A(B)}$ centered on point $A$ and with radius $AB$ **[1S running total]**.
2. Construct $\bigcirc{C(B)}$ centered on point $C$ **[2S running total]**.

   - $\bigcirc{A(B)}$ also intersects $\bigcirc{C(B)}$ at another point $E \ne B$.
3. Construct $\overleftrightarrow{CE}$ **[3S running total]**.

   - $\overleftrightarrow{CE}$ also intersects $\bigcirc{C(B)}$ at another point $F \ne E$.
   - Note that $\overline{EF}$ is a diameter of $\bigcirc{C(B)}$.
4. Construct $\overleftrightarrow{BF}$ **[4S running total]**.

   - $\overleftrightarrow{BF}$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OC}$ at the required point $D$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION** Stumbled upon this construction that meets the constraint of using only three elementary steps. As noted for the previous construction, Euclid himself notes that the required point $D$ is the intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{OC}$ on one hand and of a line $\overleftrightarrow{BF} \parallel \overline{OA}$.
>
> [image: 3S construction to this problem]
>
> 1. Construct $\bigcirc{A(B)}$ centered on point $A$ and with radius $AB$ **[1S running total]**.
>
>    - $\bigcirc{A(B)}$ also intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OB}$ at another point $E \ne B$.
> 2. Construct $\bigcirc{C(E)}$ **[2S running total]**.
>
>    - $\bigcirc{C(E)}$ also intersects $\bigcirc{A(B)}$ at another point $F \ne E$.
> 3. Construct $\overleftrightarrow{BF}$ **[3S running total]**.
>
>    - $\overleftrightarrow{BF}$ intersects $\overleftrightarrow{OC}$ at the required point $D$.

**PROOF OF SOLUTION** Auxiliary lines were added to the construction figure above, resulting in the proof figure below. Points common to both figures are named as they are in the construction figure.

[image: Proof of 3S construction to this problem]

1. $\overline{AC} \cong \overline{AC}$ by identity, $\overline{AE} \cong \overline{AF}$ as radii of $\bigcirc{A(E)}$, and $\overline{CE} \cong \overline{CF}$ as radii of $\bigcirc{C(E)}$. Therefore, $\Delta{CAE} \cong \Delta{CAF}$ by SSS congruence, and thus $\angle{CAE} \cong \angle{CAF}$.
2. Let $G$ be the intersection of $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{EF}$. $\overline{AG} \cong \overline{AG}$ by identity, $\overline{AE} \cong \overline{AF}$ as noted previously, and $\angle{CAE} \cong \angle{CAF}$ as concluded in the previous paragraph. Therefore, $\Delta{AGE} \cong \Delta{AGF}$ by SAS congruence, and thus $\angle{AGE} \cong \angle{AGF}$. The congruency of these angles, combined with how they form a linear pair, mean that $\angle{AGE}$ is a right angle.
3. $\overline{BE}$ is a diameter of $\bigcirc{A(B)}$ included by $\angle{BFE}$. By the Inscribed Angle Theorem, $\angle{BFE}$ is a right angle.
4. Because $\angle{AGE}$ and $\angle{BFE}$ are right angles and therefore congruent to each other, and because they are corresponding angles formed as $\overleftrightarrow{EF}$ transverses $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{BF}$
   = $\overleftrightarrow{BD}$, the Corresponding Angles Postulate concludes that $\overleftrightarrow{AC} \parallel \overleftrightarrow{BD}$.
5. Thus, $OA/OB = OC/OD$ by [Proposition 12 from Book VI of Euclid's *Elements*](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI12.html), which is really just an application of the Corresponding Angles Postulate and SSS similarity to the parallel lines $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{BD}$ transversed by $\overleftrightarrow{OC}$. *Q.E.D.*
   $\blacksquare$

Comment: +1. Nicely done. Importantly, the construction requires that the entire line $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ exists, since $O$ may separate $E$ from $A$. (The app screenshot shows the line, but the description "**Given** $\angle O$ with two rays entirely constructed" isn't quite so clear on the matter.)

Comment: @Blue: Given has been updated to reflect your point. Thank you very much!